# Expression Engine 2.7 FreeForm Hidden Captcha

Tags: ee2, solspace-freeform

My client has just come back to be with a new requirement to not use the EE captcha functionality and instead implement a hidden captcha.

Is this possible with freeform, if not how would you tackle it?

I have done some research but I cannot find anythign with regards to a hidden captcha and freeform.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [Snaptcha](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/snaptcha) add-on.